# Read all rows and properties from List<T>

Tags: c#, reflection

```
    public string ClassListToText<T>(List<T> obj)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            str.Append(property.Name + "|");
        }
        str.Append(">>");

        foreach (T row in obj)
        {
            string txtRow = string.Empty;
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                txtRow += row[property.Name].ToString().Trim();
                txtRow += "|";
            }
            txtRow += ">";
            str.AppendLine(txtRow);

        }
        return str.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to read all List rows and properties and write it to text file. I can't find how to do this part of code "row[property.Name]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netcore-3.1):

```
txtRow += property.GetValue(row).ToString().Trim();
```